# ./stat file is not getting generated inside the doc root path of dispatcher

Tags: aem

I have set the /statfileslevel "4" and added headers and enabled TTL . But stat file is not getting generated in the doc root path .

When i send a flush request through the dispatcher flush agent cache ( from Author ACS Commons)  is not getting deleted and also could not see any stat file inside the doc root path .

Is there any configuration that needs to be added further .

Answer (score 0):

If you use TTL-based caching on dispatcher then event-based invalidations like page activation or similar is not affecting those resources. So basically resources with cache-control headers are not affected by touching .stat files.

Maybe Delete cache type from ACS flush agent would delete files (included ttl), but not 100%, need's to be tested.

Good example of what and how the enableTTL dispatcher directive is working.

https://github.com/adobe/aem-dispatcher-experiments/blob/main/experiments/enableTTL/README.md

Also very good documentation about caching from adobe.

https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/experience-manager-learn/dispatcher-tutorial/chapter-3.html?lang=en#overview